# What is `%setup -q` in RPM spec?

Tags: macros, rpm, specifications

If you create a `.spec` file with ViM, the editor will use a skeleton for it. Quite handy!

It bugs me however that the generated `%setup` macro has this `-q` flag which I could not find anywhere.

I didn't find any mention on the [max-rpm guide page on macros](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-specref-macros.html), and does not get expanded by `rpmspec`: `rpmspec --eval '%setup'` only returns `%setup`, and the `-p` does not change anything. It is not mentioned in other [relevant docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-rpm-packages/index.html) also.

With further investigation I noticed that there's plenty of macros which don't get expanded by `rpmspec`, even if I could find plenty of macros in `/usr/lib/rpm` (on my Fedora).

So I'm wondering:

1. What is the `-q` for?
2. How come I cannot see all expansions? Am I missing something?
3. The aforementioned Max RPM guide claims the existence of a `--test` flag for `rpm -b` commands. I could see on my system there's no `rpm -b`, and actually I do all the job with `rpmbuild`. In `rpmbuild` there's no `--test` flag. How do I see the expanded scripts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*What is the -q for?*

See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html-single/RPM_Guide/index.html#id366540

It stands for: Run quietly with minimal output.

*How come I cannot see all expansions? Am I missing something?*

I'm not 100% sure, but %setup is very likely the *term* and handled by rpm internals. It is the same as %if, which is not expanded as well.

*The aforementioned Max RPM guide claims the existence of a --test flag for rpm -b commands. I could see on my system there's no rpm -b, and actually I do all the job with rpmbuild. In rpmbuild there's no --test flag. How do I see the expanded scripts?*

The **Max RPM** is very old. It was written in 2000. And not updated since then. While it is still one of the best and most comprehensive guides. Some things changed. This is one of them. I am not aware of any equivalent of --test. There exist on "rpm --eval" and "rpm --showrc". The last one shows all defined macros on your system.

Comment: Here's a link to the Max RPM page on `%setup`, which I think is (sadly) still the most complete doc out there:

https://rikers.org/rpmbook/node70.html#SECTION03541000000000000000

Comment: The above link to the RPM Guide no longer works.
As of today, There is documentation at:
    https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/
which MIGHT have useful information.

Answer (score 1):

> The aforementioned Max RPM guide claims the existence of a --test flag for rpm -b commands. I could see on my system there's no rpm -b, and actually I do all the job with rpmbuild. In rpmbuild there's no --test flag.

That is because back in the days the `/usr/bin/rpm` binary file used to do *both* rpm package install/update/remove operation as well as building rpm packages. In order to make the code less complex the build related stuff was extracted to a separate `rpmbuild` binary later, thus moving the `-b` option from `rpm` to `rpmbuild` and for some reason the `--test` option did not follow along.

---

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html contains full documentation of `%setup` et al (although possibly somewhat outdated).